# Ordering by 'field index'

Tags: mysql

Can i use order by in mysql query but not with columns name but column index or type order by 'first column' or something like that ?

Like

```
Select * from `users` order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MySQL supports referring to columns in [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) by their position:

> Columns selected for output can be referred to in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions. Column positions are integers and begin with 1 […]

This is also reflected by the syntax description of `ORDER BY`:

> ```
> [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
>   [ASC | DESC], ...]
> ```

However:

> Use of column positions is deprecated because the syntax has been removed from the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. For example if you use 1000 instead of 1, you'll get something like this error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '1000' in 'order clause'
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible, see [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

> [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}

```
mysql> select * from kcreate order by 1;
+-------+-------+
| k1    | k2    |
+-------+-------+
|     1 | 99999 |
| 12117 | 10294 |
+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from kcreate order by 2;
+-------+-------+
| k1    | k2    |
+-------+-------+
| 12117 | 10294 |
|     1 | 99999 |
+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```